# Error on multi module project triggering dataflow pipeline: Unable to convert url (jar:file:/home/java/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/) to file

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Getting an error when trying to execute a Dataflow pipeline using spring boot war / swagger:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert url (jar:file:/home/java/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/) to file.
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineResources.detectClassPathResourcesToStage(PipelineResources.java:55)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:266)
... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineResources.detectClassPathResourcesToStage(PipelineResources.java:52)
... 79 more
```

It seems to be failing when trying to set the Runner for dataflow and bringing the dependency to the project:

```
options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
```

I have tried already to include the plugin for self-contained jars for dataflow:

```
    <build>
     <!--Self contained jar compilation for dataflow : https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/-->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>MAIN-CLASS-HERE</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have found a similar thread but without a clear resolution to the problem: [IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert url (jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/) to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961440/illegalargumentexception-unable-to-convert-url-jarfile-app-jar-boot-inf-cla)

Comment: Hi all, got to bypass the org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineResources.detectClassPathResourcesToStage setting the resources with options.setFilesToStage.

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, can you post it as an answer and mark it as solution? Thank you

Comment: Hi Anton, I'll do it. Thks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got to bypass the org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PipelineResources.detectClassPathResourcesToStage setting the resources with options.setFilesToStage.